# Java framework for distributed system

Tags: java, performance, distributed

I am looking for a library (or a combination of libraries) to build a java distributed system, made of several applications exchanging data through several pairwise connections (no mapreduce). For the moment I did an expolration of existing libraries and I could only discard what I'v found. Here are my requirements:

- Easy discovery of systems at runtime (possibly through a central server/directory)
- Lightweight and low latency messages (no CORBA, RMI, SOAP,. etc.)
- Decentralized communications (no LINDA like)
- Easy enough to use and learn (no JXTA)
- Compatible with GPL license (so GPL, BSD, etc.)

Do you have any suggestion ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you familiar with [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/)? You could use it to design your own architecture. They provide easy-to-use multicast abstraction.

Comment: You could always try it, and find out!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of JGroups, but I recently discovered [hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) and will probably give it a try. It might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a peek at Terracotta ( http://www.terracotta.org/ )

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at Jade if you like multi-agents paradigm http://jade.tilab.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think Apache River (formerly Jini) should at least be mentioned. It never received too much attention, probably also because it had (don't know if it still has) a rather steep learning curve. Anyhow, it is under active development:

http://river.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

[JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/), ok, ok, it is not a framework but they have a number of projects that sound just like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Redisson](https://redisson.org) - distributed and scalable Java data structures (`BitSet`, `BloomFilter`, `Set`, `SortedSet`, `Map`, `ConcurrentMap`, `List`, `Queue`, `Deque`, `BlockingQueue`, `BlockingDeque`, `ReadWriteLock`, `Semaphore`, `Lock`, `AtomicLong`, `CountDownLatch`, `Publish / Subscribe`, `RemoteService`, `ExecutorService`, `LiveObjectService`, `ScheduledExecutorService`) on top of high performance [Redis](http://redis.io) server.